# git svn migration failing with svn 1.8

Tags: git, svn, version-control, osx-lion

I'm following the steps in:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client

to move an svn repository to git. My local svn version is:

`$ svn --version
svn, version 1.8.10 (r1615264)
compiled Aug 25 2014, 10:52:18 on x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0`

git version:

`$ git --version
git version 2.1.0`

When I clone the repository I get an error reading the local file system format:

```
$ git svn clone file:///tmp/test-svn -s
Initialized empty Git repository in /private/tmp/test-svn/.git/
Couldn't open a repository: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///tmp/test-svn': Unable to open an ra_local session to URL: Unable to open repository 'file:///tmp/test-svn': Expected FS format between '1' and '4'; found format '6' at /usr/local/Cellar/git/2.1.0/lib/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 310
```

According to this svn release note FS format 6 was introduced in svn 1.8:
http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#revprop-packing

Could it be the git 2.1 Perl script isn't yet compatible with this svn release? More importantly how can I get this svn repository converted to git?

Comment: I tried upgrading git to the latest version 2.2 and still get the same error.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I got an answer on the git-users email list.

The solution is to run a local svnserver and use the `svn` protocol when running `git svn clone` instead of the `file` protocol. That avoids `git-svn` needing to parse the svn 1.8 file format.

Suppose your repository is in a directory `/path/to/repository/test-svn`. Change into the `/tmp` directory and run

```
svnserve -d -r /path/to/repository
```

Then you can run

```
git svn clone svn://127.0.0.1/test-svn -s
```

Afterwards, stop the svnserver and delete the temporary svn repository.

Comment: `cd` to the parent directory of `test-svn` (or whatever your SVN repo is called—I'm using that example). Then run `svnserve -d --foreground -r .`. Your repo URL is now `svn://localhost/test-svn`.