# 'Can't create session Unable to connect to repo' when trying to migrate svn to git

Tags: git, svn, repository, git-svn

I'm trying to migrate my local svn repo to git. I've been following the steps on this post: [How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-repository-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository?noredirect=1&lq=1)

More specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/79188/365237) (seemed like the simplest). The problem is whenever I try and fetch from my svn repo I keep getting the :

*Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///mypathtorepo'*

My repo is currently sitting on my local computer which is why I'm using the 'file:///' directory path. I've also tried 'svn://localhost/mypathtorepo' to no avail. How do I fix this?

Comment: so what directory path you actually have? `file://` is the protocol, slash after that is part of path.

Comment: Is this a one-time conversion or do you plan to commit back from the Git repository to the SVN repository?

Comment: This will be a one time conversion. I want to completely switch to git. I've read some places converting the protocol to svn:// has helped other people in this situation, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. And the path I would use would be file:///c:/Users/UserName/Desktop/repo

Comment: did you try "git svn clone <path to repository>"

Comment: Similar problem for specific versions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240428/git-svn-migration-failing-with-svn-1-8/27325713

Answer (score 1):

file:/// is most likely not working due to your SVN repo having a FS format that is newer that what Git is aware of.

Your second approach with svn://localhost was in the right direction.  However, you need to host the repo with the svnserve command line utility.  Something like:

```
svnserve -d -R --root file://path/to/repo
```

After getting svnserve to properly host the repo, you can use the path beginning with: `svn://localhost`

Answer (score -3):

`git-svn` is **not** the right tool for one-time conversions of repositories or repository parts. It is a great tool if you want to use Git as frontend for an existing SVN server, but for one-time conversions you should **not** use `git-svn`, but `svn2git` which is much more suited for this use-case.

There are pleny tools called `svn2git`, the probably best one is the KDE one from https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git. I strongly recommend using that `svn2git` tool. It is the best I know available out there and it is very flexible in what you can do with its rules files. And as it needs the repository files locally anyway, you have the best pre-requisites.

If you are not 100% about the history of your repository, `svneverever` from http://blog.hartwork.org/?p=763 is a great tool to investigate the history of an SVN repository when migrating it to Git.

---

Even though `git-svn` is easier to start with, here are some further reasons why using the KDE `svn2git` instead of `git-svn` is superior, besides its flexibility:

- the history is rebuilt much better and cleaner by `svn2git` (if the correct one is used), this is especially the case for more complex histories with branches and merges and so on
- the tags are real tags and not branches in Git
- with `git-svn` the tags contain an extra empty commit which also makes them not part of the branches, so a normal `fetch` will not get them until you give `--tags` to the command as by default only tags pointing to fetched branches are fetched also. With the proper svn2git tags are where they belong
- if you changed layout in SVN you can easily configure this with `svn2git`, with `git-svn` you will loose history eventually
- with `svn2git` you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily
- or combine multiple SVN repositories in the same SVN root into one Git repository easily
- the conversion is a gazillion times faster with the correct `svn2git` than with `git-svn`

There are many reasons why `git-svn` is worse and the KDE `svn2git` is superior. :-)

Comment: I use git-svn each time when i want to mirror sources from svn to git and don't see any problems with it except those where delevopers of git could just break it in next git release.

Comment: I dont understant most of them, because on my side i don't have such problems you listed. For example, `if you changed layout in SVN...you will loose history eventually`. You don' t lose anything here, you just save exactly particular history for the branch in SVN. If something goes out of the branch or tag - it does not saving. Or `with svn2git you can also split one SVN repository into multiple Git repositories easily`, with git-svn you could do the same. It just a matter of scripting.

Comment: Not in more advanced situations. Believe me, I transformed quite some repos already. In very basic situations `git-svn` produces a halfway acceptable result, but still not really good and it needs muuuch time compared to KDE `svn2git`. Try to convert a repo with 100.000 commits. You will wait maybe 2 or 3 weeks with `git-svn` add have a worse result than with `svn2git` that will be finished in 1 or 2 days. If you are satisfied with the `git-svn` result and wait time, by all means use it. It is just a strong recommendation by me to use the better tool instead.